# Redirection loop issue with PHP code

Tags: php, google-chrome, loops, redirect

I'm new to the forums here, so apologies if i'm forgetting to include information that could be helpful.

I've successfully built a login page for my test website, and have been trying to implement redirection functionality that will redirect the user to the homepage if their session already exists.

Here is my code:

```
<?php


if (empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
        header('Location: home');
        die();
}else{
        header('Location: index.php');
        die();
}
?>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
<!--HTML form stuff goes here-->
```

I'm using Chrome, but always get the "This webpage has a redirect loop" message whenever I reload. I'm sure it has something to do with the else{} statement, as it works perfectly fine when it's excluded and when a session DOES exist.

Some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `as it works perfectly fine when it's excluded and when a session DOES exist.` ... but where is `session_start();` on your code ??

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran Whoops, forgot to include that in my original code. No change, unfortunately.

Comment: I can't answer my own questions at this level, but I can say that I've fixed this now. I removed the unnecessary else{} statement, included the session_start(); and changed "empty" to "isset". Everything works! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

That file can never be viewed in the browser, as it will always redirect to either `home` or `index.php`. If the code you have pasted is from either `home` or `index.php` it's a redirect loop. And if that's the case there's no reason to redirect as you're already at that page.

Comment: Just to clarify; yes, this code is from the index.php page.

Comment: Then there's no reason to do inclide the `else` clause, it's what's causing the loop. And it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

ideally you must have given data of all files

i am making an assumption that all your files have same code segment as you specified above for login session verification

then i can say possibly this is happening your login page redirects to index.php which again does same checking and again redirects to itself which is index.php and so on ... and your browser gets stuck in redirect loop.

for solving this problem you can do this your login.php code checks for both cases if user is logged in or not and redirects suitably

**login.php**

```
if (empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
// not logged in redirect
        header('Location: home');
        die();
}else{
//logged in redirect
        header('Location: index.php');
        die();
}
```

and in index.php check only if user is not logged in , if he isn't then send back to login.php else stay here

**index.php**

```
if (empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
// not logged in redirect
        header('Location: login.php');
        die();
}else{
//logged in 
//do nothing
}
```

similarly you can check if already logged in ,in home/index.php file and do suitably . Though my suggested solution isn't as efficient as it can be , I hope it gives you the central idea as to why you are in redirect loop.